# unable to launch opera using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This command didn't launch opera. thrown error "Runner threw exception on construction".

```
driver=new OperaDriver();
driver.get("url");
```

Even this didn't launch opera but thrown same error "Runner threw exception on construction".

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "path of OperaDriver.exe");
driver=new OperaDriver();
driver.get("url");
```

This didn't launch opera thrown error "Could not start Opera: launcher unable to start binary".

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.opera(); //in this command opera is stroked. 
capabilities.setCapability("opera.binary", "path of OperaDriver.exe");  
driver = new OperaDriver(capabilities);
```

But by using the 2nd and 3rd step codes with the following path "C:\Program Files\Opera\launcher.exe", opera LAUNCHED but URL/website  didn't open in the browser.

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) What programming language are you using?  (2) Are you using selenium-webdriver or selenium-rc?  Based on your code, I'm guessing webdriver.  (They are very different products)

Comment: @Isowen 1) they are using Java. 2) they are using WebDriver.  you can tell by the code.

Comment: this probably has to do with your versions @Devi, what Version of **Opera**, **OperaDriver**, and **Selenium** are you using.

Comment: Opera version is 28.0, OperaDriver-1.0, Selenium-2.45

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Separate OperaDriver
You can also use OperaDriver as a standalone dependency in your project. Download the package from the [Github project's download section](https://github.com/operasoftware/operaprestodriver/downloads) and extract it to a location of your choice. For your own projects include the lib/ directory on your classpath, for example:

```
   javac -classpath "lib/*:." Example.java
```

you can also refer the selenium wiki for opera [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/OperaDriver) once.

Comment: i am getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Devi\\Downloads\\operadriver_win32\\operadriver.exe");
      driver =new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with Windows 10, Selenium 3.5.2, Opera 52.0 and OperaDriver 2.35 and the following code works for me.

```
DesiredCapabilities capablities=DesiredCapabilities.opera();
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "C:\\automation\\opera\\operadriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Opera\\launcher.exe");
capablities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
OperaDriver driver = new OperaDriver(capablities);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("how to use opera with selenium");
```